# How to get a list of wifi connections around me with its RSSI strength using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, wifi, rssi

My app should scan Wifi signals around and list the network's name and its RSSI.

I can't find any clue on Google about how to do it. Could someone give an example or at least point somewhere else where I can find the answer?

Comment: You can't do this on iOS, at least not without a jailbroken device. Apple doesn't let you interact with wifi settings directly on iOS.

Comment: @Gavin, not event just to see what's around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think its possible ! It doesnt matter if its Swift or Objective-C nor C++, the basic principle of iOS is that only system can connect to WiFi or turn on off those system setting. All you can get is info about the currently connected network. App sandbox in ios limits all other possibility.

It is only possible to get the SSID of the network that you are currently connected to.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will have to figure out a workaround for this issue.

Comment: @LucasRezende Welcome,

Comment: @LucasRezende dont forgot to post and tag me in comment if you find any solution. :)